# Socket.io cellular handshake iOS Time Out

Tags: ios, socket.io, wifi, nsurlconnection, handshake

I am making a socket.io handshake call via standard HTTP NSURLConnection, the weird thing is I only get a response when I am connected via Wifi, otherwise the connection times out. I understand that sockets do not work over Wifi and should use the xhr-polling for a cellular connection, but the HTTP connection only working via Wifi doesnt make sense, because of this I cant even poll because I cant connect at all....

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The problem ended up being on the server (although it was a while ago, I believe it was a firewall or configuration error), not an iOS issue. The following library was being used and works very well if anybody comes across this and is curious:

https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc